# javascript not sorting when there are commas in the strings on the table

Tags: javascript, sorting, overriding, reverse

I am using the standard Javascript "sort" function to sort elements in a column in a table. The problem is the person asked me to add commas every 3rd digit and a . for the last 2 decimal places.

My first search was working fine when I had:

456345.00
456948.00
456949.34

But now it does not sort when I put in

456,949.34

I need a way to override the .sort and .reverse javascript functions!

Or I need to somehow remove the commas and . and fraction part and then sort accordingly and then add the details.

Here is the example source code

```
 $('#results').on("click", "th", function(){ 

    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray();
    rows.splice(-1, 1);
    rows.sort(comparer($(this).index()));
    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text() }



  });
```

Comment: Can you post the table html? is the ID of your table results ?

Comment: Yes "results" is the div that the information is returns. I am calling a PHP script via AJAX that returns the results into the #results div which is a table. It used to sort out nicely but now the person asked to add commas to make the numbers more readable and now the sort gets confused with the commas and does not sort correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript array `sort` takes a comparer function that works on the values in the actual array. There's no need to read external data (what I'm assuming your comparer is trying to do).

This should suffice

```
function comparer(a, b) {
  a = parseFloat(a.replace(/,/g,''));
  b = parseFloat(b.replace(/,/g,''));

  return a-b;

}
```

This will take the array and (in the sort) remove commas, convert to a float and return the comparison leaving you with correctly sorted array that will still have your comma formatted items.

Comment: This is my current code below. Can you modify it so it still works and does what you recommend?

function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Wainage's answer...replace the entire piece of code that you have posted with the following. I have removed the commas and the decimals from the numbers because in my understanding, when you compare 12.34 with 12.23 the answer is going to be the same with or without the decimal.

so 12.34 > 12.23 and 1234 > 1223

In my fiddle, i have used large numbers with commas eg. 555,444,440.00. I am assuming that the numbers are less than 9007199254740991 which is the limit of the size of integers.

Here is a link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pparas/Zhd2X/694/

```
$('th').click(function(){
        var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
        var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray();
        rows.splice(-1, 1);
        rows.sort(comparer($(this).index()));
        this.asc = !this.asc
        if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
    })
    function comparer(index) {
        return function(a, b) {
            var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index);
            if(($.isNumeric(valA.replace(/[,.]/g,''))) && ($.isNumeric(valB.replace(/[,.]/g,'')))){
                valA = parseInt(valA.replace(/[,.]/g,''));
                valB = parseInt(valB.replace(/[,.]/g,''));
            }
            return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
        }
    }

    function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html() }
```

Thanks,

Paras